# What kind of weird little insect is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

What kind of insect is this?

I found it in my work room.

I live in the city of São José dos Campos, São Paulo, Brazil

[image]

Comment: Please indicate the approximate size of your specimens. Also, if you have a clearer/brighter picture of the top of the insect, please provide that as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably a [nymphal stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nymph_(biology)) of a [stink bug (aka shield bug)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatomidae).

Based on the roundness of your specimens, I'd suspect that they represent possibly the 1st or 2nd [instar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instar) development stage.

I am unsure of the species currently, though I suspect this is an image of the adult (wrongfully labeled as a "bed bug" at its source):

[image]

<sup>Source: [Shutterstock](https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bed-bug-nymph-on-vine-260nw-1271194588.jpg)</sup>

I will dig into the Brazilian fauna to see if I can get you a species...